# DataTables: total a column - except for rows with specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have the code to total a column, but I have subgroups that already have totals. Can I total each number in the column EXCEPT the gray total rows?
[image]

```
var table = $('#datatable');
var leng = table.find("tr:first").children().length;

    // add totals to new row
            for (var i = 0; i < leng; i++) {

                var total = api
                .column(i)
                .data()
                    .reduce(function (a, b) {
                        // return if it's not a value from the gray row
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    });

                // correct any html mistakes that slip through
                if (isNaN(intVal(total)))
                    total = '';

                table.find("tfoot tr:first th").eq(i).html(total);
            };
```

Comment: maybe the grey rows have a specific class?

Comment: They do, but how would that look code wise? The class is 'sgrouptotal'

Comment: use `.not('.sgrouptotal')` to exclude everything that have class `sgrouptotal`

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the `:not` selector on the `rows()` API method and calculate the sum based on the remaining rows? Very small example, add the sum of col#1 to the footer in a callback :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    drawCallback: function () {
        var api = this.api(),
            sum = 0;
        api.rows(":not('.sgrouptotal')").every(function() {
            sum += parseFloat(this.data()[0]);
        });    
        $(api.column(0).footer()).text(sum);
    }
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/j38bmagj/**

The above should be fairly easy to extend to multiple columns. Calculate the sum for col #4 in the same loop like `sum4 += this.data()[4]` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

What about just doing that?

```
i = 0;          
$('#datatable tr:first tr').each(function(key, value){
    if(!$(this).hasClass("sgrouptotal"){
        i += parseInt(value.text());
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work because i refers to the columns, of which there is 4 - not the 12 rows.